# how to get random post id by using post type

Tags: posts, post-type

I need to get a post ID's random manner...

Something I tried like this,

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'adzones');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $id = the_ID();
  echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id=".$id."]");
endwhile;
```

Here I'm try to display an add post inside the loop but it won't work for me...

And also It retrieve only all post ID's in asc order...

How should I do this..someone help me..

Thank you,

Comment: `the_ID()` **prints** the ID. You want `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: Thanks  toscho... But how to get random ID's !!...

Comment: What are you referring by `random id` ? Do you want to set the value of `$id` randomly from `adzones` post type post ids ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far I understood you want to set the value of `$id` randomly from `adzones` post type post ids. I hope this helps you-

```
$args = array( 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '1', 
    'post_type' => 'adzones'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $id = get_the_ID();
    echo do_shortcode("[pro_ad_display_adzone id=".$id."]");
endwhile;
```